# EL1007E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null and Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: " ***** "

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I just learnt how to make a simple form and how to display the entered details in a new webpage in spring using thymeleaf. So I decided to try it on a more complicated form that I had created a few months ago that also included css. I am relatively new to spring so I might be overlooking an error in my code. But this error is driving me crazy. I've found out out that if I do a null check in my survey results html file then the result page loads but each of the fields(name, age, email, etc.) are empty.

Controller

```
package com.example.demo.b;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.example.demo.user.SurveyData;

@Controller
public class SurveyForm {
    
    @RequestMapping("/survey")
    public String formDisplay(Model mdl) {
        mdl.addAttribute("surveyData", new SurveyData());
        return "Survey";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/survey-results")
    public String surveyResults(SurveyData srv) {
        return "SurveyResults";
    }
}
```

Survey HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Survey Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/Style.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="title">freeCodeCamp Survey Form</h1>
      <p id="description">Thank you for taking the time to help us improve the platform</p>
      <div class="container">
        <form method="post" action='/survey-results' th:object="${surveyData}">
        <fieldset>
          <label for="name">Name <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" th:field="${surveyData.name}" required></label>
          <label for="email">Email <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email" th:field="${surveyData.email}" required /></label>
        <label for="number">Age <input id="number" type="number" min="10" max="100" placeholder="Your Age" th:field="${surveyData.age}" required /></label>
        <label for="dropdown">Which option best describes your current role?
          <select th:field="${surveyData.role}" required>
            <option value="">(select current role)</option>
            <option value="1">Student</option>
            <option value="2">Full Time Job</option>
            <option value="3">Full Time Student</option>
            <option value="4">Prefer not to say</option>
            <option value="5">Other</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Would you recommend freeCodeCamp to a friend?</legend>
          <label for="definitely"><input type="radio" id="definitely" class="inline" th:field="${surveyData.recommendation}" th:value="Definitely" checked>Definitely</label>
          <label for="maybe"><input type="radio" id="maybe" class="inline" th:field="${surveyData.recommendation}" th:value="Maybe">Maybe</label>
          <label for="not sure"><input type="radio" id="not sure" class="inline" th:field="${surveyData.recommendation}" th:value="NotSure">Not Sure</label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <label for="feature">What is your favorite feature of freeCodeCamp?
            <select th:field="${surveyData.favourite}" required>
              <option value="">Select an option</option>
              <option value="1">Challenges</option>
              <option value="2">Projects</option>
              <option value="3">Community</option>
              <option value="4">Open Source</option>
              </select>
              </label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>           
        <legend>What would you like to see improved? (Check all that apply)</legend>
        <label for="front end projects"><input type="checkbox" id="front end projects" class="inline" th:field="${surveyData.improvement}" th:value="Front-endProjects">Front-end Projects</label>
        <label for="back end projects"><input type="checkbox" id="back end projects" class="inline" th:field="${surveyData.improvement}" th:value="Back-endProjects">Back-end Projects</label>
        <label for="data visualisation"><input type="checkbox" id="data visualisation" class="inline" th:field="${surveyData.improvement}" th:value="DataVisualization">Data Visualization</label>
        <label for="challenges"><input type="checkbox" id="challenges" class="inline" th:field="${surveyData.improvement}" th:value="Challenges">Challenges</label>
        <label for="open source community"><input type="checkbox" id="open source community" class="inline" th:field="${surveyData.improvement}" th:value="OpenSourceCommunity">Open Source Community</label>
        <label for="gitter help rooms"><input type="checkbox" id="gitter help rooms" class="inline" th:field="${surveyData.improvement}" th:value="GitterHelpRooms">Gitter help rooms</label>
        <label for="videos"><input type="checkbox" id="videos" class="inline" th:field="${surveyData.improvement}" th:value="Videos">Videos</label>
        <label for="city meetups"><input type="checkbox" id="city meetups" class="inline" th:field="${surveyData.improvement}" th:value="CityMeetups">City Meetups</label>
        <label for="wiki"><input type="checkbox" id="wiki" class="inline" th:field="${surveyData.improvement}" th:value="Wiki">Wiki</label>
        <label for="forum"><input type="checkbox" id="forum" class="inline" th:field="${surveyData.improvement}" th:value="Forum">Forum</label>
        <label for="additional courses"><input type="checkbox" id="additional courses" class="inline" th:field="${surveyData.improvement}" th:value="AdditionalCourses">Additional Courses</label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <label for="comments">Any comments or suggestions?
          <textarea id="comments" name="comments" row="5" column="5" placeholder="Enter your comment here" th:field="${surveyData.comment}"></textarea>
          </label>
          </fieldset>
          <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
          </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";

body {text-align:center; font-size:17px; font-family: Arial; background:linear-gradient(45deg, gray, black) }


h1,p {color: #a1a1a1;margin: 1em auto;}

.container {width:40%; margin: 20px auto;
padding: 2em; color: white; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.45); text-align:left; border-radius:10px}

label {display:block; margin: 10px 0;}

fieldset {border:0;padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #2e2e30; margin-top:10px;}

input,select,textarea {margin: 5px 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 2em; border-radius:10px; padding:5px;}

.inline {width: unset;
  margin: 0 2px 0 0;
  vertical-align:middle}

input[type="submit"] {display: block; width: 30%; margin:10px auto; border: 2px solid #2e2e30; font-weight: bold; padding:10px; border-radius:10px;}
```

Making the constructor with getter setters

```
package com.example.demo.user;

public class SurveyData {
    private String name, email, role, recommendation, favourite, improvement, comment;
    private int age;
    
    public SurveyData() {
        
    }
    
    public SurveyData(String name, String email, String role, String recommendation, String favourite, String improvement,
            String comment, int age) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.role = role;
        this.recommendation = recommendation;
        this.favourite = favourite;
        this.improvement = improvement;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public String getRecommendation() {
        return recommendation;
    }

    public String getFavourite() {
        return favourite;
    }

    public String getImprovement() {
        return improvement;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public void setRecommendation(String recommendation) {
        this.recommendation = recommendation;
    }

    public void setFavourite(String favourite) {
        this.favourite = favourite;
    }

    public void setImprovement(String improvement) {
        this.improvement = improvement;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    
}
```

Finally the result HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Survey Results</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <h1>Here are your entered details:</h1>
        <h4>Check for any discrepancies</h4>
    
        <p>Name: <span th:text="${srv.name}"></span></p>
        <p>Email: <span th:text="${srv.email}"></span></p>
        <p>Age: <span th:text="${srv.age}"></span></p>
        <p>Current Role: <span th:text="${srv.role}"></span></p>
        <p>Would you recommend: <span th:text="$srv.recommendation}"></span></p>
        <p>Favorite feature: <span th:text="${srv.favourite}"></span></p>
        <p>Improvements: <span th:text="${srv.improvement}"></span></p>
        <p>Comment: <span th:text="${srv.comment}"></span></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the error code

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Nov 29 13:34:41 IST 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/SurveyResults.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/SurveyResults.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1103)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1077)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:372)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:192)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "srv.name" (template: "SurveyResults" - line 11, col 18)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "srv.name" (template: "SurveyResults" - line 11, col 18)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:292)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:144)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:304)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:278)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:186)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:124)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:109)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:297)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:402)
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseOpenElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:159)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:710)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:224)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:111)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:416)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:98)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:114)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:338)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:265)
    ... 69 more
```

Comment: Your `th:field` expressions are wrong. Instead of `${surveyData.name}` use `*{name}` for proper binding and remove the `id` and `name` attributes, those will be automatically generated due to the `th:field`. Next your controller should add `@ModelAttribute` to your `SurveyData srv` element.

Comment: @M.Deinum the results HTML page does show up but but each of the fields are empty(Name:     , Age:     , Email:       ,etc)